# AWS : Recaptcha not showing in jsp page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, recaptcha

I have a jsp page hosted on Amazon AWS. I am using `recaptcha`

```
<div class="form-group"><br/><label>Prove you are not a robot</label>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lc8wPkSAAAAADdG4ofT8_JWUKTlJXtEeXeO1ohK "></script>
      <noscript>
         <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lc8wPkSAAAAADdG4ofT8_JWUKTlJXtEeXeO1ohK " height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
         <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
         <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
      </noscript>                            
</div>
```

while run in JSP it shows `Prove you are not a robot Input error: Invalid referer`